# MotionEyeOS without internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, motioneyeos

I am trying to build a small system which include a rPi and rPi Zero. rPi act as local wifi hotspot and rPi zero connect to rPi hotspot.Then I access zero camera through rPi. My diagram looks like this.

[image]

It works totally fine if I have a LAN connection. Once I remove the lan connection motionEyeOs won't stream any data. And even it disconnect from wifi and go to boot loop.

So my question, is there any way we can make motionEyeOs works with out actual internet ?.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question: You can set link_watch="false" in /data/etc/watch.conf

But this come with a few other problems:

- If your camera boots without network connection (internet), it has no time set (your videos and images could get overwritten)
- If your camera boots without or looses network connection (internet), the camera does not try to reconnect and you have no other chance and have to connect a keyboard an monitor to it

A hardware clock would help for the first problem but I am still searching for a solution for the second. If you already have one, I would appreciate it, if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md

This is what I use for an offline video recorder and it only needs the software and a power source..Camera also but you get the idea. Keep your image (os) small as possible as this can fill an sd card fast. If I remember right, I used 800 x 600 and it would use a gig an hour.